# How can I update the <valuePrefix> value in a multiselect or checkbox when the related token value is updated? (Splunk-Enterprise)

Tags: xml, splunk, splunk-dashboard

I have a Dropdown token being used as the  in a Multiselect input. The Multiselect seems to only set the  tag's value during dashboard initialization. I can get a change in the dropdown to take effect on the Multiselect when refreshing the page in the web browser, but not when changing the Dropdown value or when refreshing the panel. This same behaviour applies to the Checkbox input.

Here is my code for the panel in question:

```
<panel depends="$Global_Tok$">
      <title>CPU</title>
      <input type="multiselect" token="CPU_Field_Global_Multi">
        <label>Fields</label>
        <choice value="(pctUser) AS User">User</choice>
        <choice value="(pctIdle) AS Idle">Idle</choice>
        <choice value="(Load) AS &quot;Load (-Idle)&quot;">Load</choice>
        <choice value="(pctIowait) AS IO_Wait">IO_Wait</choice>
        <choice value="(pctNice) AS Nice">Nice</choice>
        <choice value="(pctSystem) AS System">System</choice>
        <default>"(Load) AS ""Load (-Idle)""",(pctUser) AS User,(pctIdle) AS Idle,(pctIowait) AS IO_Wait,(pctNice) AS Nice,(pctSystem) AS System</default>
        <initialValue>(Load) AS "Load (-Idle)",(pctUser) AS User,(pctIdle) AS Idle,(pctIowait) AS IO_Wait,(pctNice) AS Nice,(pctSystem) AS System</initialValue>
        <valuePrefix>$Global_Function$</valuePrefix>
        <delimiter> </delimiter>
      </input>
      <input type="checkbox" token="CPU_Fields_Cbx">
        <label>Fields</label>
        <choice value="(pctUser) AS User">User</choice>
        <choice value="(pctIdle) AS Idle">Idle</choice>
        <choice value="(Load) AS &quot;Load (-Idle)&quot;">Load</choice>
        <choice value="(pctIowait) AS IO_Wait">IO_Wait</choice>
        <choice value="(pctNice) AS Nice">Nice</choice>
        <choice value="(pctSystem) AS System">System</choice>
        <valuePrefix>$Global_Function$</valuePrefix>
      </input>
      <chart>
        <search>
          <query>host=$HOST_SELECTION$ source=cpu
| multikv
| search CPU=$CPU_Core_Global_Tok$
| eval Load=(pctIdle-100)*-1
| timechart span=$Global_Span$ $CPU_Fields_Cbx$</query>
          <earliest>$Global_Time.earliest$</earliest>
          <latest>$Global_Time.latest$</latest>
          <refresh>1m</refresh>
          <refreshType>delay</refreshType>
        </search>
        <option name="charting.axisTitleX.text">Time</option>
        <option name="charting.axisTitleY.text">CPU Util (%)</option>
        <option name="charting.axisY.maximumNumber">100</option>
        <option name="charting.chart">line</option>
        <option name="charting.drilldown">none</option>
        <option name="refresh.display">progressbar</option>
      </chart>
    </panel>
```

In this example code, the panel is only using the Checkbox input token for the search, but the same issue is applied when I use the Multiselect as well. The token I am updating with the Dropdown input is "$Global_Function$".

The code for the Global Function dropdown input is as follows:

```
<input type="dropdown" token="Global_Function" depends="$Global_Tok$">
      <label>Function</label>
      <choice value="avg">Average</choice>
      <choice value="max">Maximum</choice>
      <default>avg</default>
      <initialValue>avg</initialValue>
    </input>
```

I have not been able to get the Multiselect or Checkbox inputs to change their initial  value upon the Function Dropdown changing. So if anyone has suggestions on how to accomplish this, then I am all ears.